# Unable to run console command yii2

Tags: yii2

I am trying to run `yii` but unable to this. I am getting following error:

commond :   `php yii`

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: yii\console\Request::parsers'

in /var/www/html/alpha/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:201

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/alpha/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(529): yii\base\Component->__set('parsers', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/alpha/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\console\Request), Array)
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/alpha/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(381): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/alpha/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\console\\Req...', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/alpha/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(348): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\console\\Req...', Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/html/alpha/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(135): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/alpha/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(219): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('request')
#8 /var/www/html/alpha/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): yii\console\Application->getRequest()
#9 /var/www/html/alpha/html/yii(31): yii\base\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parsers` property is available in `yii\web\Request`, not in `yii\console\Request`.

Probably you have got your console configuration merged with web configuration where this property is set. If so, make sure console configuration is set with separate `request` component setup. If this is not the case of configs merge remove this property in console configuration.

Comment: in my common/config/main.php   'request' => [
                        'parsers' => [
                            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
                        ]
                    ],

but it's not in my console config. How can i remove it in console ?

Comment: Since 2.0.10 you can add in console config: 'request' => [ 'parsers' => new \yii\helpers\UnsetArrayValue() ], for previous versions you need to make sure console configuration is not merged with common config.

Answer (score 0):

It`s work for my issue:
Edit file : console/config/main.php

```
'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => new \yii\helpers\UnsetArrayValue(), //Add this line
        ],
    ],
```